# How much weight can a drywall support on both sides if everything is hung on the 2x4s (not on the drywall sheet)?

Tags: drywall, safety, support, resistance

How much weight can a drywall support on both sides if everything is hung on the 2x4s (not on the drywall sheet)?

This drywall doesn't go all the way up to the ceiling. It separates the kitchen from the family room. It already holds cabinetry and china on the kitchen side and I want to mount a 77" TV and a wall-mount electric fireplace on the family room side. This drywall connects to two lateral drywalls and to the kitchen backwall which is made of block, making a square (the kitchen space).

Comment: What is the spacing of the studs? In the US it is normally either 16 inches or 24 inches.

Comment: A picture would help. (The back wall of your kitchen doesn’t matter.)

Comment: FYI. Once the studs are  covered in drywall the end result is called a WALL. Drywall is a product  that is attached to the studs.  So for clarity; you are taking about walls  that are complete with drywall on them and not just drywall by itself, ? Now, the wall you are concerned about is **Pony wall** or half wall because it does not extend up to the ceiling. The fact that the other side of the pony wall has cabinetry means it adds structural integrity to the pony wall. **if you stand on the side  you want to add a TV onto and grab the top of the pony wall and pull it does it move at all?**

Comment: To the previous question, the studs are 16 in apart. And you are correct, this is a WALL, by the definition you listed above. So it's a pony wall connected not to the ceiling, but to 2 side pony walls and then to the back wall (block). It does not move one bit when pulled. on the kitchen side, the cabinetry contains plenty of china, so I'm wondering if it's unsafe to now mount both the 77 in TV plus the fireplace (which itself is about 150lbs) onto the family room side. Again, yes, it's a pony wall (thank you so much for explaining, very helpful). Still wondering if wall will be destroyed

Comment: And this is a one-story house (not sure whether that's relevant), so I take it this is not a load bearing wall